# Create activity plot for speech and non-speech by two speakers

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have speech data for two speakers indiating the `start` and `end` times when they speak as well as the silences in-between, grouped by `minute`s:

```
df <- structure(list(speaker = c(NA, "A", NA, NA, "B", NA, "A", NA, NA, "B", "A"), 
                     start = c(0, 20000, 35000, 60000, 65000, 80000,1e+05, 110000, 120000, 140000, 180000), 
                     end = c(20000, 35000,60000, 65000, 80000, 1e+05, 110000, 120000, 140000, 180000, 195000), 
                     minute = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L)), 
                row.names = c(NA,-11L), class = "data.frame")
```

I'd like to **visualize** the speakers' speech and non-speech activity in a graphic like this one, where the speakers are assigned colors and their (non-)speech times are depicted in rows each representing a minute:

[image]

How can this graph in this or similar form be programmed? I'm open to any solution, be it `base R` or `ggplot2`.

**EDIT**:

One should perhaps start by relating all `start` and `end`times to the same sequence from 0 to 60000:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(minute) %>%
  mutate(start = start - 60000*minute,
         end = end - 60000*minute)
# A tibble: 11 x 4
# Groups:   minute [4]
   speaker start   end minute
   <chr>   <dbl> <dbl>  <int>
 1 NA          0 20000      0
 2 A       20000 35000      0
 3 NA      35000 60000      0
 4 NA          0  5000      1
 5 B        5000 20000      1
 6 NA      20000 40000      1
 7 A       40000 50000      1
 8 NA      50000 60000      1
 9 NA          0 20000      2
10 B       20000 60000      2
11 A           0 15000      3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach where I convert the speaker identity to a number and use that to vertically offset it from the minute.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(x = start, xend = end, 
               y = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(speaker)))/10,
               yend = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(speaker)))/10,
               color = speaker)) +
  geom_segment(size = 4) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:10, labels = paste0(0:10, "min"), name = NULL)
```

[image]

EDIT -- based on suggestion to realign the timing by minute, and to include NA:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  replace_na(list(speaker = "NA")) %>%
  mutate(start = start - 60000*minute,
         end = end - 60000*minute,) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = start, xend = end, 
               y = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(speaker)))/10,
               yend = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(speaker)))/10,
               color = speaker)) +
  geom_segment(size = 4) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:10, labels = paste0(0:10, "min"), name = NULL)
```

[image]

Comment: That's pretty good. Just why is NA not showing?

Comment: In my actual data I get this warning `Warning message:
Removed 408 rows containing missing values (geom_segment).`Why is that and how can that be prevented?

Comment: It sounds like 408 rows are missing either start / end / minute / speaker and so can't plot a segment for those rows. I'd suggest putting in a `View()`  just before the `ggplot` line, and look to see where it's NA.