# Plotting gaze movements by multiple speakers in a single plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

**EDIT**:

I have a very large dataframe, of which I'm giving here the first 900 rows:

```
df4 <- structure(list(Gaze_by = c("C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", 
"C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C", "C"), AOI = c("*", "A", 
"*", "*", "A", "*", "*", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", 
"*", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "*", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", 
"A", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", 
"*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", 
"*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "*", "*", "B", "B", "*", "*", "*", 
"B", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "B", "B", "*", "*", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "*", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "*", "B", "B", 
"B", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", 
"A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "*", "*", "A", "*", "*", "A", "*", "*", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", 
"*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", 
"*", "A", "*", "B", "*", "B", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "*", "*", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "*", "*", 
"*", "*", "*", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "*", "A", "A", "A", "*", 
"A", "*", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", 
"*", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "*", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", 
"*", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "*", "A", 
"*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", 
"A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", 
"*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", 
"*", "A", "A", "*", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", 
"*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "*", 
"*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", 
"*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "*", "*", "*", "B", "B", "*", "B", "B", "*", "B", "*", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "*", "B", "B", "B", "*", "B", "*", "A", 
"*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "*", 
"A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "*", "*", "*", 
"A", "*", "A", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", 
"A", "A", "A", "*", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", 
"*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", 
"A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", 
"A", "*", "A", "*", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "*", "*", "A", 
"A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", 
"*", "*", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", 
"*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "*", "*", "A", "*", 
"A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", 
"*", "*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", 
"*", "B", "B", "B", "B", "*", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "*", "*", "*", "B", "*", "*", "B", "*", "*", "A", "A", 
"A", "*", "*", "A", "*", "*", "A", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", 
"B", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "*", "A", 
"*", "A", "*", "*", "B", "B", "B", "B", "B", "*", "B", "B", "B", 
"B", "B", "*", "*", "*", "*", "*", "B", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", 
"*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", 
"A", "*", "*", "A", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", 
"A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", "*", "B", 
"B", "B", "B", "*", "*", "*", "B", "*", "*", "*", "*", "B", "*", 
"*", "*", "*", "*", "A", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "*", "A", 
"*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "*", "*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "A", 
"A", "*", "*", "A", "*", "*", "*", "*", "A", "*", "A", "A", "*", 
"A", "A", "*", "A", "A", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", "A", "*", 
"A"), minute = c(0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 
6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 
7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 
8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 
9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 9L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 10L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 
11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L, 11L), start_pm = c(0, 
251, 1976, 5127, 5717, 6783, 6830, 7685, 8410, 9889, 9990, 12000, 
14051, 14253, 14589, 18051, 18129, 19503, 20246, 20647, 20994, 
21427, 21905, 25032, 25086, 25210, 25318, 26610, 26970, 27759, 
28123, 33603, 34188, 35297, 35599, 36703, 37810, 39042, 39290, 
39558, 39575, 41395, 41883, 43276, 43416, 43809, 48516, 48643, 
49010, 49996, 50022, 50496, 50674, 51836, 52595, 53286, 57019, 
57434, 57584, 0, 1354, 5257, 5927, 7833, 9567, 10677, 14057, 
14333, 14597, 14673, 16084, 17232, 17245, 17637, 17654, 20414, 
20989, 23599, 27361, 27701, 29407, 29706, 29807, 30075, 31025, 
31092, 31370, 32904, 34828, 35944, 36620, 37119, 37511, 39737, 
40928, 43208, 43521, 47450, 47748, 51578, 53239, 53371, 53678, 
56048, 56843, 57261, 59559, 59949, 0, 151, 773, 1151, 2672, 3043, 
5233, 5251, 5442, 5451, 6821, 7206, 8706, 9051, 9869, 10061, 
15794, 16138, 16437, 16627, 21127, 21361, 21394, 22451, 25753, 
26787, 27554, 28294, 28471, 29527, 36760, 37071, 38371, 38427, 
38651, 38694, 39673, 39934, 41587, 42355, 42496, 43240, 46889, 
46936, 47761, 48559, 49882, 54200, 54504, 0, 3106, 3768, 4826, 
4949, 6249, 6393, 6706, 6721, 7406, 7572, 7978, 8242, 8593, 8600, 
9934, 10059, 10382, 10660, 11274, 11694, 11857, 12746, 13019, 
13424, 14065, 14551, 16952, 17316, 17804, 18181, 20114, 20737, 
21914, 22970, 23647, 23804, 24214, 24537, 25014, 25170, 28330, 
28675, 29952, 30129, 30425, 30849, 35670, 36370, 39242, 39939, 
45230, 45764, 49530, 50264, 52462, 52949, 53630, 53970, 54094, 
54625, 54965, 55689, 56215, 56555, 57279, 59779, 0, 15, 39, 499, 
1082, 1274, 1390, 1582, 2680, 2830, 4287, 7720, 12238, 12256, 
13083, 13433, 14487, 14908, 16027, 20800, 21212, 22930, 23337, 
24239, 24676, 24815, 25354, 25903, 26054, 28727, 29012, 30790, 
31230, 32442, 33372, 33469, 33659, 33856, 36192, 36320, 37092, 
37417, 38966, 39592, 39783, 40126, 40894, 40905, 43887, 44019, 
46595, 47119, 48155, 49018, 54098, 54697, 55232, 55958, 56235, 
56482, 56773, 56948, 56991, 57427, 58113, 58149, 58568, 58958, 
59131, 59468, 0, 172, 1553, 2053, 2070, 2416, 2425, 3968, 4682, 
9146, 9431, 9708, 9950, 10854, 10998, 11334, 11815, 13888, 13903, 
14115, 14243, 14452, 14575, 14607, 14877, 15073, 15214, 22277, 
23577, 24797, 24957, 25223, 25627, 25642, 26309, 26597, 27083, 
27183, 27693, 28193, 28593, 30826, 31037, 34880, 35264, 35551, 
35788, 37493, 38993, 39450, 39760, 40820, 40867, 41151, 44025, 
44419, 45793, 46230, 49060, 49497, 51497, 51527, 52347, 53547, 
53931, 55997, 56393, 58347, 58481, 59733, 0, 460, 883, 1492, 
1497, 1896, 1897, 2027, 2493, 2660, 4239, 4519, 4527, 4848, 6950, 
7167, 7897, 9459, 9676, 11356, 12814, 13031, 13386, 13486, 13506, 
13799, 15089, 15299, 15632, 15932, 16232, 16390, 16760, 17202, 
17698, 17908, 18241, 18541, 18655, 18682, 19022, 19084, 19794, 
19841, 20194, 20502, 20618, 20898, 22315, 22687, 25151, 25352, 
26118, 26302, 27194, 27385, 28251, 28449, 30261, 30592, 31283, 
31945, 37781, 39165, 39448, 39912, 40583, 41092, 43053, 44582, 
46262, 47553, 47984, 48257, 51361, 51381, 51833, 51902, 51982, 
52481, 53509, 53659, 53829, 55012, 55325, 56683, 57206, 57282, 
57425, 57632, 58292, 0, 451, 1282, 1425, 1879, 2492, 2966, 3515, 
3738, 3825, 4140, 5859, 6033, 6885, 7206, 9029, 9820, 11729, 
12679, 13379, 13444, 13774, 13825, 13999, 14244, 16092, 16599, 
17662, 18769, 20620, 21556, 22196, 22371, 23480, 23928, 24985, 
25090, 25153, 25295, 25466, 25596, 26161, 26679, 27129, 27957, 
28152, 29301, 29454, 30396, 30566, 31149, 31342, 37179, 38029, 
39719, 40779, 42132, 42342, 44696, 45442, 47990, 48644, 49164, 
49654, 50104, 50408, 51310, 51752, 54642, 54690, 54998, 56475, 
56679, 56682, 57133, 57379, 57749, 58133, 58282, 58709, 58789, 
59099, 59649, 0, 19, 709, 833, 1179, 1679, 2342, 2549, 3775, 
5675, 5809, 6479, 6483, 6609, 6999, 7244, 7265, 7442, 7757, 7795, 
8227, 8485, 8707, 8802, 8962, 9127, 9257, 9990, 10157, 10297, 
10480, 11064, 11190, 14053, 14449, 15097, 15690, 15823, 15990, 
16257, 16581, 16797, 16923, 17223, 19680, 19890, 20013, 20390, 
20613, 20790, 20960, 21233, 21713, 21777, 22090, 22646, 23647, 
23781, 23913, 25064, 25480, 25823, 25944, 26128, 26290, 26623, 
27180, 27490, 28133, 28410, 28493, 28590, 29780, 30097, 31380, 
31547, 32949, 32950, 33505, 33530, 34071, 34653, 34953, 35156, 
36449, 37286, 37449, 38020, 38453, 38671, 38834, 39235, 39451, 
40051, 40747, 40884, 43688, 45754, 45951, 46511, 47107, 47150, 
47281, 48674, 49214, 49641, 50181, 51007, 51247, 51541, 52734, 
52841, 52998, 53159, 53314, 56583, 57531, 59341, 59661, 0, 221, 
1721, 2265, 2374, 2615, 4027, 4732, 5181, 5765, 6531, 7521, 8811, 
9074, 9647, 9774, 10014, 10166, 10666, 11374, 11650, 12131, 12412, 
12421, 12555, 13204, 13419, 13606, 13935, 14652, 17230, 17870, 
18102, 18412, 18836, 19075, 20253, 22209, 22476, 22690, 22819, 
23571, 23793, 25086, 25210, 25637, 26391, 26653, 26953, 29916, 
30386, 30411, 31376, 31871, 32097, 33389, 34213, 34863, 35427, 
35435, 35778, 35796, 36513, 37001, 37170, 37344, 37476, 38170, 
38271, 38403, 40420, 40616, 40870, 41320, 41373, 41410, 41583, 
41916, 41986, 42129, 42462, 43572, 43753, 43794, 47089, 47337, 
48031, 48364, 50110, 53192, 53562, 54180, 54334, 55884, 58615, 
58697, 59867, 0, 174, 1870, 1926, 2526, 2543, 3207, 3691, 3696, 
4943, 5937, 8007, 9124, 9551, 9963, 11121, 11136, 11607, 11817, 
11827, 12318, 12548, 12704, 13670, 14077, 15012, 15067, 15367, 
16332, 17330, 17702, 18087, 18922, 19482, 19662, 21772, 21939, 
24582, 25392, 25402, 26032, 26089, 26172, 27102, 27102, 27102, 
27866, 28068, 28272, 28658, 29602, 30689, 32222, 32755, 33102, 
33335, 33906, 34426, 34856, 35562, 36819, 38868, 39039, 39192, 
39335, 39486, 39532, 41582, 43002, 43202, 44295, 45109, 45286, 
46413, 51246, 51380, 55245, 55546, 55631, 57143, 57523, 57582, 
58057, 58426, 59426, 0, 716, 896, 4726, 4864, 6275, 7088, 7268, 
8909, 9770, 11265, 11461, 11655, 14216, 14310, 18409, 20346, 
21137, 21758, 22587, 23837, 24564, 24754, 26123, 26259, 27627, 
28337, 28687, 29494, 32737, 33237, 35287, 35494, 35557, 35583, 
36794, 37742, 41780, 41909, 41923, 41960, 42960, 43664, 48913, 
49094, 49606, 50083, 50444, 50766, 51393, 51583, 53277, 53539, 
54760, 54883, 55083, 55847, 56260, 56347, 56830, 57397), end_pm = c(251, 
1976, 5127, 5717, 6783, 6830, 7685, 8410, 9889, 9990, 12000, 
14051, 14253, 14589, 18051, 18129, 19503, 20246, 20647, 20994, 
21427, 21905, 25032, 25086, 25210, 25318, 26610, 26970, 27759, 
28123, 33603, 34188, 35297, 35599, 36703, 37810, 39042, 39290, 
39558, 39575, 41395, 41883, 43276, 43416, 43809, 48516, 48643, 
49010, 49996, 50022, 50496, 50674, 51836, 52595, 53286, 57019, 
57434, 57584, 60000, 1354, 5257, 5927, 7833, 9567, 10677, 14057, 
14333, 14597, 14673, 16084, 17232, 17245, 17637, 17654, 20414, 
20989, 23599, 27361, 27701, 29407, 29706, 29807, 30075, 31025, 
31092, 31370, 32904, 34828, 35944, 36620, 37119, 37511, 39737, 
40928, 43208, 43521, 47450, 47748, 51578, 53239, 53371, 53678, 
56048, 56843, 57261, 59559, 59949, 60000, 151, 773, 1151, 2672, 
3043, 5233, 5251, 5442, 5451, 6821, 7206, 8706, 9051, 9869, 10061, 
15794, 16138, 16437, 16627, 21127, 21361, 21394, 22451, 25753, 
26787, 27554, 28294, 28471, 29527, 36760, 37071, 38371, 38427, 
38651, 38694, 39673, 39934, 41587, 42355, 42496, 43240, 46889, 
46936, 47761, 48559, 49882, 54200, 54504, 60000, 3106, 3768, 
4826, 4949, 6249, 6393, 6706, 6721, 7406, 7572, 7978, 8242, 8593, 
8600, 9934, 10059, 10382, 10660, 11274, 11694, 11857, 12746, 
13019, 13424, 14065, 14551, 16952, 17316, 17804, 18181, 20114, 
20737, 21914, 22970, 23647, 23804, 24214, 24537, 25014, 25170, 
28330, 28675, 29952, 30129, 30425, 30849, 35670, 36370, 39242, 
39939, 45230, 45764, 49530, 50264, 52462, 52949, 53630, 53970, 
54094, 54625, 54965, 55689, 56215, 56555, 57279, 59779, 60000, 
15, 39, 499, 1082, 1274, 1390, 1582, 2680, 2830, 4287, 7720, 
12238, 12256, 13083, 13433, 14487, 14908, 16027, 20800, 21212, 
22930, 23337, 24239, 24676, 24815, 25354, 25903, 26054, 28727, 
29012, 30790, 31230, 32442, 33372, 33469, 33659, 33856, 36192, 
36320, 37092, 37417, 38966, 39592, 39783, 40126, 40894, 40905, 
43887, 44019, 46595, 47119, 48155, 49018, 54098, 54697, 55232, 
55958, 56235, 56482, 56773, 56948, 56991, 57427, 58113, 58149, 
58568, 58958, 59131, 59468, 60000, 172, 1553, 2053, 2070, 2416, 
2425, 3968, 4682, 9146, 9431, 9708, 9950, 10854, 10998, 11334, 
11815, 13888, 13903, 14115, 14243, 14452, 14575, 14607, 14877, 
15073, 15214, 22277, 23577, 24797, 24957, 25223, 25627, 25642, 
26309, 26597, 27083, 27183, 27693, 28193, 28593, 30826, 31037, 
34880, 35264, 35551, 35788, 37493, 38993, 39450, 39760, 40820, 
40867, 41151, 44025, 44419, 45793, 46230, 49060, 49497, 51497, 
51527, 52347, 53547, 53931, 55997, 56393, 58347, 58481, 59733, 
60000, 460, 883, 1492, 1497, 1896, 1897, 2027, 2493, 2660, 4239, 
4519, 4527, 4848, 6950, 7167, 7897, 9459, 9676, 11356, 12814, 
13031, 13386, 13486, 13506, 13799, 15089, 15299, 15632, 15932, 
16232, 16390, 16760, 17202, 17698, 17908, 18241, 18541, 18655, 
18682, 19022, 19084, 19794, 19841, 20194, 20502, 20618, 20898, 
22315, 22687, 25151, 25352, 26118, 26302, 27194, 27385, 28251, 
28449, 30261, 30592, 31283, 31945, 37781, 39165, 39448, 39912, 
40583, 41092, 43053, 44582, 46262, 47553, 47984, 48257, 51361, 
51381, 51833, 51902, 51982, 52481, 53509, 53659, 53829, 55012, 
55325, 56683, 57206, 57282, 57425, 57632, 58292, 60000, 451, 
1282, 1425, 1879, 2492, 2966, 3515, 3738, 3825, 4140, 5859, 6033, 
6885, 7206, 9029, 9820, 11729, 12679, 13379, 13444, 13774, 13825, 
13999, 14244, 16092, 16599, 17662, 18769, 20620, 21556, 22196, 
22371, 23480, 23928, 24985, 25090, 25153, 25295, 25466, 25596, 
26161, 26679, 27129, 27957, 28152, 29301, 29454, 30396, 30566, 
31149, 31342, 37179, 38029, 39719, 40779, 42132, 42342, 44696, 
45442, 47990, 48644, 49164, 49654, 50104, 50408, 51310, 51752, 
54642, 54690, 54998, 56475, 56679, 56682, 57133, 57379, 57749, 
58133, 58282, 58709, 58789, 59099, 59649, 60000, 19, 709, 833, 
1179, 1679, 2342, 2549, 3775, 5675, 5809, 6479, 6483, 6609, 6999, 
7244, 7265, 7442, 7757, 7795, 8227, 8485, 8707, 8802, 8962, 9127, 
9257, 9990, 10157, 10297, 10480, 11064, 11190, 14053, 14449, 
15097, 15690, 15823, 15990, 16257, 16581, 16797, 16923, 17223, 
19680, 19890, 20013, 20390, 20613, 20790, 20960, 21233, 21713, 
21777, 22090, 22646, 23647, 23781, 23913, 25064, 25480, 25823, 
25944, 26128, 26290, 26623, 27180, 27490, 28133, 28410, 28493, 
28590, 29780, 30097, 31380, 31547, 32949, 32950, 33505, 33530, 
34071, 34653, 34953, 35156, 36449, 37286, 37449, 38020, 38453, 
38671, 38834, 39235, 39451, 40051, 40747, 40884, 43688, 45754, 
45951, 46511, 47107, 47150, 47281, 48674, 49214, 49641, 50181, 
51007, 51247, 51541, 52734, 52841, 52998, 53159, 53314, 56583, 
57531, 59341, 59661, 60000, 221, 1721, 2265, 2374, 2615, 4027, 
4732, 5181, 5765, 6531, 7521, 8811, 9074, 9647, 9774, 10014, 
10166, 10666, 11374, 11650, 12131, 12412, 12421, 12555, 13204, 
13419, 13606, 13935, 14652, 17230, 17870, 18102, 18412, 18836, 
19075, 20253, 22209, 22476, 22690, 22819, 23571, 23793, 25086, 
25210, 25637, 26391, 26653, 26953, 29916, 30386, 30411, 31376, 
31871, 32097, 33389, 34213, 34863, 35427, 35435, 35778, 35796, 
36513, 37001, 37170, 37344, 37476, 38170, 38271, 38403, 40420, 
40616, 40870, 41320, 41373, 41410, 41583, 41916, 41986, 42129, 
42462, 43572, 43753, 43794, 47089, 47337, 48031, 48364, 50110, 
53192, 53562, 54180, 54334, 55884, 58615, 58697, 59867, 60000, 
174, 1870, 1926, 2526, 2543, 3207, 3691, 3696, 4943, 5937, 8007, 
9124, 9551, 9963, 11121, 11136, 11607, 11817, 11827, 12318, 12548, 
12704, 13670, 14077, 15012, 15067, 15367, 16332, 17330, 17702, 
18087, 18922, 19482, 19662, 21772, 21939, 24582, 25392, 25402, 
26032, 26089, 26172, 27102, 27102, 27102, 27866, 28068, 28272, 
28658, 29602, 30689, 32222, 32755, 33102, 33335, 33906, 34426, 
34856, 35562, 36819, 38868, 39039, 39192, 39335, 39486, 39532, 
41582, 43002, 43202, 44295, 45109, 45286, 46413, 51246, 51380, 
55245, 55546, 55631, 57143, 57523, 57582, 58057, 58426, 59426, 
60000, 716, 896, 4726, 4864, 6275, 7088, 7268, 8909, 9770, 11265, 
11461, 11655, 14216, 14310, 18409, 20346, 21137, 21758, 22587, 
23837, 24564, 24754, 26123, 26259, 27627, 28337, 28687, 29494, 
32737, 33237, 35287, 35494, 35557, 35583, 36794, 37742, 41780, 
41909, 41923, 41960, 42960, 43664, 48913, 49094, 49606, 50083, 
50444, 50766, 51393, 51583, 53277, 53539, 54760, 54883, 55083, 
55847, 56260, 56347, 56830, 57397, 57804)), row.names = c(NA, 
-900L), groups = structure(list(Gaze_by = "C", .rows = structure(list(
    1:900), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", "vctrs_vctr", 
"list"))), row.names = 1L, class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

The dataframe contains gaze data (column `AOI`) of different speakers (column `Gaze_by`) and temporal data. What I'd like to do is plot the gazes for **all speakers** in the same plot. So far what I can do is filter the dataframe for individual speakers and plot their individual gazes over time. For example, for speaker "A":

```
# filter:
df5 <- df4 %>%
  filter(Gaze_by == "A")

# plot:
ggplot(df5,
       aes(x = start_pm,
           xend = end_pm,
           y = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI))) / 10,
           yend = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI))) / 10,
           color = AOI)) +
  geom_segment(size = 2) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:53,
                  labels = paste0(0:53, "min"),
                  name = NULL) +
  labs(title = "Gaze activity F01, Speaker C") +
  theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank()) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("*" = "lemonchiffon",
                                 "A" = "darkorange",
                                 "B" = "lawngreen",
                                 "C" = "slateblue1"))
```

Doing likewise for speakers "B" and "C" I get three separate plots:

[image]

But how can the gazes of **all three speakers be plotted in a single graph**?

The kind of plot I have in mind is roughly like this:

[image]

Comment: Looks very similar to [speech production plots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67889173/create-activity-plot-for-speech-and-non-speech-by-two-speakers). How would you say this is different as to your desired plot result as it appears you intend it to resolve to time, as opposed to perhaps more interestingly 'where at each when', which implies having something analogous to eyetracking data.

Comment: Yes, indeed, the present plots have been developed on the basis of the speech production plots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems pretty close to your expected outcome: would this work with your actual data?

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Create some "fake" data with all 3 "Gaze-by's",
# shuffle the AOIs between the different "Gaze-by's"
# and only keep data for the first two minutes
df <- df4 %>% 
  bind_rows(df4 %>% mutate(Gaze_by = "B", AOI = sample(AOI)), 
            df4 %>% mutate(Gaze_by = "A", AOI = sample(AOI))) %>% 
  filter(minute %in% 0:2)

df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = start_pm,
             xend = end_pm,
             y = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(Gaze_by))) / 6,
             yend = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(Gaze_by))) / 6,
             color = AOI)) +
  geom_segment(size = 3) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:53,
                  labels = paste(0:53, "min", " Gaze_by_A\n Gaze_by_B\n Gaze_by_C", sep = " "),
                  name = NULL) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("*" = "lemonchiffon",
                                 "A" = "darkorange",
                                 "B" = "lawngreen",
                                 "C" = "slateblue1")) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 18) +
  theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank())
```

[image: example_4.png]

### (My original answer)

I've done something similar in the past by faceting the plots; in this case perhaps you could facet by minute and Gaze_by to get your desired outcome?

E.g.

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Create some "fake" data with all 3 "Gaze-by's" and
# only keep data for the first three minutes
df <- df4 %>% 
  bind_rows(df4 %>% mutate(Gaze_by = "B"), 
            df4 %>% mutate(Gaze_by = "A")) %>% 
  filter(minute %in% 0:3)

# Plot the data
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = start_pm,
             xend = end_pm,
             y = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI))) / 10,
             yend = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI))) / 10,
             color = AOI)) +
  geom_segment(size = 2) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:53,
                  labels = paste0(0:53, "min"),
                  name = NULL) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("*" = "lemonchiffon",
                                 "A" = "darkorange",
                                 "B" = "lawngreen",
                                 "C" = "slateblue1")) +
  theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~ minute + Gaze_by, ncol = 1,
             scales = "free_y", strip.position = "right")
```

[image: example_2.png]

You can also tweak this approach a fair bit to suit, e.g.

```
# Load libraries
library(tidyverse)

# Create some "fake" data with all 3 "Gaze-by's",
# shuffle the AOIs between the different "Gaze-by's"
# and only keep data for the first two minutes
df <- df4 %>% 
  bind_rows(df4 %>% mutate(Gaze_by = "B", AOI = sample(AOI)), 
            df4 %>% mutate(Gaze_by = "A", AOI = sample(AOI))) %>% 
  filter(minute %in% 0:2)

# Plot the data
df %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = start_pm,
             xend = end_pm,
             y = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI))) / 10,
             yend = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(AOI))) / 10,
             color = AOI)) +
  geom_segment(size = 2) +
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:53,
                  labels = paste0(0:53, "min"),
                  name = NULL) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("*" = "lemonchiffon",
                                 "A" = "darkorange",
                                 "B" = "lawngreen",
                                 "C" = "slateblue1")) +
  theme_classic(base_size = 14) +
  theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank()) +
  facet_wrap(~ minute + Gaze_by, ncol = 1,
             scales = "free_y", strip.position = "right",
             labeller = labeller(minute = label_both,
                                 Gaze_by = label_both)) +
  theme(strip.text = element_text(size = 8))
```

[image: example_3.png]

Comment: Thanks for all the great work! I do not think that the transformation from `df4` to `df` is necessary. I've omitted this step and plotted my actual data directly - it worked beautifully!

Comment: Hi. Just thought I might draw your attention to this question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68374987/speech-gaze-activity-plot-in-ggplot2 - has a 200 points bounty on it!

Comment: Hi Chris, at first glance it seems doable (glances per utterance) but the logistics are going to be complicated - I'll see if I can figure out a good approach when I've got some spare time.