# speech-gaze activity plot in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have data with `Utterance`s by speakers in conversation as well as their gazes to one another. The speakers' gazes are in columns `A_aoi`, `B_aoi`, and `C_aoi`, the gaze durations are in `A_aoi_dur`, `B_aoi_dur`, and `C_aoi_dur`. Here's a reproducible snippet of the data:

```
df0 <- structure(list(Line = c(105L, 106L, 107L, 109L, 110L, 111L, 112L, 
113L, 114L, 115L, 116L), Speaker = c("ID01.A", NA, "ID01.A", 
NA, "ID01.B", NA, "ID01.A", NA, "ID01.A", NA, "ID01.C"), Utterance = c("so you've ↑obviously↑ thought about it obviously: (.) have made a decision (.) I'm !head!ing in this door (.) one of the cleaning ladies at the UB !grabb!ed my elbow", 
"(0.662)", "and said (.) ~no no no !this! is the !womens'! bathroom~=", 
"(0.015)", "=((v: gasps))=", "(0.166)", "=NOW", "(0.622)", "!how! this always plays out ", 
"(0.726)", "[when was] that¿="), UttStart = c(163898L, 172500L, 
173162L, 176100L, 176115L, 176800L, 176966L, 177372L, 177994L, 
179328L, 180054L), UttEnd = c(172500, 173162, 176100, 176115, 
176800, 176966, 177372, 177994, 179328, 180054, 180668), UttDur = c(8602, 
662, 2938, 15, 685, 166, 406, 622, 1334, 726, 614), A_aoi = c("*B*C*B*C*B*C*B*C*B*C", 
"C*", "*B*C*C", "C", "C*", "*", "*C", "C", "C*B", "B*", "*"), 
    A_aoi_dur = c("21,516,79,333,200,634,233,651,17,2332,33,400,33,518,17,532,33,1900,119,1", 
    "414,248", "1124,412,116,533,600,153", "15", "616,69", "166", 
    "153,253", "622", "204,151,979", "219,507", "614"), B_aoi = c("A*A*A*A*A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A", "A*", "*A*A", "A*A", "A*A"), 
    B_aoi_dur = c("475,130,567,137,1983,313,787,1400,2810", "662", 
    "2938", "15", "685", "166", "406", "398,224", "76,136,284,838", 
    "108,571,47", "116,270,228"), C_aoi = c("A", "A", "A*A*A", 
    "A", "A", "A", "A", "A*A", "A", "A*A", "A"), C_aoi_dur = c("8602", 
    "662", "1058,123,1300,144,313", "15", "685", "166", "406", 
    "264,351,7", "1334", "125,323,278", "614")), row.names = c(NA, 
-11L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

**EDIT**: new test data with temporally **overlapping** `Utterances`:

```
df0 <- structure(list(Line = 137:145, 
                      Speaker = c("ID01.A", "ID01.A-Q", NA, "ID01.A", "ID01.A-Q", "ID01.A-Q", "ID01.A-Q", "ID01.A-Q",NA), 
                      Utterance = c("↑she gra:bs my elbow (.) I turn to !look! at her↑ and she's like ~this is a (.) womens' bathroom you can't go in there~", 
                                     "~this is a (.) womens' bathroom you can't go in there~", "(0.534)", 
                                     "and I'm like ~((silent f: blank stare))~ (.) and she didn't, she was just like ~you can't go in~ (.) I'm like ~I'm a !woman!~ she said ~no you're not you can't go in~", 
                                     "~((silent f: blank stare))~", "~you can't go in~", "~I'm a !woman!~", 
                                     "~no you're not you can't go in~", "(0.487)"), 
                      UttStart = c(208845L, 211450L, 214136L, 214670L, 215409L, 218307L, 219235L, 220076L, 221368L), 
                      UttEnd = c(214136, 214136, 214670, 221368, 217117, 219050, 219885, 221368, 221855), 
                      UttDur = c(5291, 2686, 534, 6698, 1708, 743, 650, 1292, 487), 
                      A_aoi = c("C*B*C*C*B*C*", "C*B*C*", "*B", "B*C*B*C*C*B*B", "C*B", "C*B", "*", "*B","B"), 
                      A_aoi_dur = c("57,445,1100,135,199,333,866,302,832,33,468,521","530,302,832,33,468,521", 
                                    "144,390", "377,235,466,399,1268,132,268,132,433,6,716,1412,854","339,399,970", "73,6,664", "650", "438,854", "487"), 
                      B_aoi = c("A*A","A", "A", "A*A*A*A*A*A", "A", "*A*A", "*A", "A*A", "A"), 
                      B_aoi_dur = c("1691,121,3479", "2686", "534", "53,180,3333,134,253,280,203,534,1296,138,294", 
                                    "1708", "63,253,280,147", "405,245", "860,138,294", "487"), 
                      C_aoi = c("A", "A", "A", "A*A", "A", "A*", "A", "A", "A"), 
                      C_aoi_dur = c("5291", "2686", "534", "3766,734,2198", 
                                       "1708", "129,614", "650", "1292", "487")), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

What I'd like to be able to visualize is who is looking at whom and for how long for each `Utterance`, roughly like in this schematic representation:

[image]

What I can do at present is plot the gazes on a minute-by-minute scale, but just the gazes - not the `Utterance`s: [Plotting gaze movements by multiple speakers in a single plot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68287862/plotting-gaze-movements-by-multiple-speakers-in-a-single-plot). Starting from the data as above, this can be achieved by multiple transformations (shown below) but the resulting plot does not feature the `Utterance`s and it plots the gazes **per minute**, whereas I need the gazes **per `Utterance`**:

[image]

I'm fully aware that this is demanding a lot. Help with it is all the more appreciated.

```
# pivot_longer so that all gazes have their own row:
df0 <- df0 %>%
  rename_with(~ str_c(., "_AOI"), ends_with("_aoi")) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("_"), 
               names_to = c("Gaze_by", ".value"),  # 
               names_pattern = "^(.*)_([^_]+$)"
  ) %>%
  mutate(Gaze_by = sub("^(.).*", "\\1", Gaze_by)) %>%
  mutate(AOI = str_replace_all(AOI, "(?<=.)(?=.)", ",")) %>% 
  separate_rows(c(AOI, dur), sep = ",", convert = TRUE)

# compute starttimes and endtimes for gazes:
df1 <- df0 %>%
  group_by(Gaze_by) %>%
  mutate(
    end = cumsum(dur),
    start = end - dur
  )
View(df1)

# compute minutes:
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(
    # which minute does the event start in?
    minute_start = as.integer(start/60000),
    # which minute does the event end in?
    minute_end = as.integer(end/60000),
    # does the event straddle a minute mark?
    straddler = minute_end > minute_start)
View(df2)


# 1st subset of `df2`:
df2_A1 <- df2 %>%
  # filter those rows that contain events straddling minute marks:
  filter(straddler=="TRUE") %>%
  # reduce the endtime to the exact minute mark:
  mutate(end = minute_end*60000) 
View(df2_A1)

# 2nd subset of `df2`:
df2_A2 <- df2 %>% 
  # filter those rows that contain events straddling minute marks:
  filter(straddler=="TRUE") %>%
  # reduce the starttime to the exact minute mark:
  mutate(start = minute_end*60000)
View(df2_A2)

# 3rd subset of `df0`:
df2_A3 <- df2 %>%
  # filter those rows that do not contain events straddling minute marks:
  filter(!straddler == "TRUE")
View(df2_A3)

# row-bind all three subsets:
df4 <- rbind(df2_A1, df2_A2, df2_A3) %>%
  arrange(start) %>%
  mutate(
    minute = as.integer(start/60000),
    # reduce total starttimes to starttimes per minute:
    start_pm = start - 60000*minute,
    # reduce total endtimes to endtimes per minute:
    end_pm = end - 60000*minute) 

# plot gaze activity for **ALL** speakers:
df4 %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = start_pm,
             xend = end_pm,
             y = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(Gaze_by))) / 6,
             yend = minute + scale(as.numeric(as.factor(Gaze_by))) / 6,
             color = AOI)) +
  # draw segments for AOI:
  geom_segment(size = 2) +
  # reverse y-axis scale:
  scale_y_reverse(breaks = 0:max(df4$minute),
                  labels = paste(0:max(df4$minute), "min", " Gaze_by_A\n Gaze_by_B\n Gaze_by_C", sep = " "),
                  name = NULL) +
  # define custom colors:
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("*" = "lemonchiffon",
                                 "A" = "darkorange",
                                 "B" = "lawngreen",
                                 "C" = "slateblue1")) +
  # plot title:
  labs(title = "Gaze activity") +
  theme(axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank())
```

Comment: What's an "utterance"? Is it words per unit of time, or some other type of "count"? I.e. how many utterances is "and said (.) ~no no no !this! is the !womens'! bathroom~=" ?

Comment: Each string such as "and said (.) ~no no no !this! is the !womens'! bathroom~=" is one `Utterance`

Comment: One approach would be to add facets to your `ggplot` - e.g. `facet_wrap(~Utterance, ncol = 1)`, although you would need to adjust the ordering (e.g. `fct_reorder`) and formatting

Comment: @AndrewGustar If you'd like to work out a solution based on your suggestion you'd be more than welcome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a solution that gets close to what you are looking for, making use of facets.  It also uses `forcats::fct_reorder` and `stringr::str_wrap` (which are both part of the `tidyverse`).

This also wraps any long utterances and keeps the x-scale the same for all facets, rather than allowing them to stretch to fill the width.

```
df4 %>% 
  mutate(#add text for y axis labels
         Gaze_by = paste0("Gaze_by_", Gaze_by),
         #reorder facet panels, add speaker at start, and wrap to 120 characters
         Utterance = fct_reorder(str_wrap(paste0(substr(Speaker, 6, 6), ": ", 
                                                 Utterance), 
                                          120), 
                                 start_pm),
         #set a dummy end point for each utterance based on the longest one
         max_x = UttStart - min(UttStart) + max(UttDur)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = start_pm, xend = end_pm,
             y = Gaze_by, yend = Gaze_by,               #as discrete variable
             color = AOI)) +
  geom_segment(size = 3) +
  geom_point(aes(x = max_x, y = Gaze_by), alpha = 0) +  #plot invisible dummy end points
  scale_y_discrete(name = NULL, limits = rev) +         #rev to get A at the top
  facet_wrap(~Utterance, scales = "free_x", ncol = 1) +
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("*" = "lemonchiffon",
                                 "A" = "darkorange",
                                 "B" = "lawngreen",
                                 "C" = "slateblue1")) +
  labs(title = "Gaze activity") +
  theme_minimal() +                                     #removes a lot of lines etc
  theme(strip.text = element_text(color = "blue", hjust = 0), #facet strip text
        strip.background = element_rect(fill = "white", color = "white"),
        axis.title.x.bottom = element_blank())
```

[image]

To cut the utterances into 4-second chunks, you can do something like this...

```
df4 %>% group_by(Utterance) %>% 
  #work out relative durations from start of utterance and create subutterances
  mutate(relStart = start_pm - min(start_pm),
         relEnd = end_pm - min(start_pm),
         subNo = map2(relStart, relEnd, ~seq(.x %/% 4000, .y %/% 4000, 1))) %>% 
  unnest(subNo) %>% #expand one row per subutterance
  mutate(Utterance = paste0(Utterance, " (#", subNo + 1, ")"), #add sub no
         subStart = pmax(4000 * subNo, relStart),   #limits on subUtt
         subEnd = pmin(4000 * (subNo + 1), relEnd), #limits on subUtt
         start_pm = min(start_pm) + subStart,   #redefine start
         end_pm = min(start_pm) + subEnd) %>%   #redefine end
  group_by(Utterance) %>%   #regroup as Utterance has changed!
  mutate(max_x = min(start_pm) + 4000) %>%      #define dummy end points
  ungroup() %>% 
  mutate(Gaze_by = paste0("Gaze_by_", Gaze_by),
         Utterance = fct_reorder(str_wrap(paste0(substr(Speaker, 6, 6), ": ", Utterance), 
                                          120), start_pm)) %>%
  ggplot(...)   #...as per code above from this point
```

[image]

Comment: This is absolutely fantastic - as a start. Thanks a lot for the hard work. However, can the plot be changed in such a way that the gazes for each `Utterance`have their absolute durations? In the present graph it seems like the durations are all scaled so they fit the width of the panel. What I have in mind is that, as shown in the schamatic representation in the expected output, the gazes simply stop ahead of the maximal width of the plot when an utterance is short and when there are, hence, only few gazes associated with it. How could that be made possible?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I have enhanced the code above - it is a bit of a hack but it works!

Comment: Excellent work. Just one more thing: the very first `Utterance`is quite long, in fact, far longer than average, which is around 4 seconds. Can we cut `Utterances`that are longer than 4 sec. into 4 sec. chunks and plot them as well as the gazes that go with them on separate lines?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann That was a bit trickier, but I've added it to the end of my answer. Off for a lie down!

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! We're that close. Just one thing: in the actual data, `Utterances` may not always be temporally consecutive (e.g., in the case of simultaneous speech). While these overlapping `Utterances` are nicely plotted on separate lines, the millisecond timelines seem to count consecutively. (PART 1)

Comment: That is, for example, if the first `Utterance` starts at 0ms and ends at, say, 500ms and the second `Utterance` is partially simultaneous, starting at 100ms and ending at 200ms, the timeline for this second `Utterance`will show the range from 500ms to 700ms. Ideally, the timeline for the second `Utterance` should range from 100ms to 200ms. Can that be implemented?  (PART 2)

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann I think it already does this. Try shifting the fifth utterance back 10 seconds (`df4[50:53,c(4,5,10,11,16,17)] <- df4[50:53,c(4,5,10,11,16,17)] - 10000`) and it shows it correctly and in the right place. Of course, in practice, even if the utterances overlap, presumably the gazes don't!

Comment: I've added a new test data set with overlapping `Utterances`. Please try the code with that. It seems that the problem described in my previous two comments persists.

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann The problem is in your code for `df1`.  You need to `group_by` utterance as well as gaze and add back `UttStart` - something like `df1 <- df0 %>% group_by(Gaze_by, Utterance) %>% mutate(end = UttStart + cumsum(dur), ...`

Comment: Okay, that seems to work. But now the *order* in which the `Utterances` are presented is not ideal: the first line in the plot shows a short `Utterance` that is **partially overlapping** with a longer `Utterance` - in the edited test set, *all* short `Utterances` are in fact **part** of the long initial `Utterance`. Can that order be reflected in the plot? That is, can we display the long `Utterance` first and then all the short ones that are partially overlapping with it?

Comment: @ChrisRuehlemann You can just change the `fct_reorder` term from `start_pm` to something like `UttStart + subNo`